# SELECT values by another table with predefined regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, select

I would like to select rows in my table by my another table with my predefined regular expressions.
Below you can see my example tables:

**Table `code`**

```
id   |  codename
-----+------------
1    |   123456
2    |   NF123
3    |   AAA444
4    |   EEE123
5    |   EEE423
6    |   AB123E
```

**Table `validcode`**

```
 id   |  validreg
------+-----------
 1    |   [E]{3}[0-9]{3}
 2    |   NF123
```

And here is the test case on [sqlfidlle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3b0c2/3).

This is one of the my select statements I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT n.codename FROM code n
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM validcode WHERE n.codename ~* E'^' || validreg || '$');
```

I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text:
> SELECT codename FROM code n WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM validcode WHERE n.codename ~* E'^' || validreg || '$');
> ```

Is possible to do this somehow?

Comment: You don't need `where exists` or subquery. You should be fine just by joining the queries, something like `SELECT n.codename FROM code n, validcode WHERE n.codename ~* E'^' || validcode.validreg || '$'`. Probably not very efficient, though.

Comment: But still it doesn't work, i think the problem is in the string where i do the concatenating somewhere here ~* E'^' || validcode.validreg || '$'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT n.codename FROM code n, validcode
WHERE  n.codename ~* ('^' || validcode.validreg || '$')
```

Braces because otherwise the parser thinks that `n.codename ~* E'^'` is one part and to that concatenates the rest.

Also your original query would work with the additional braces.

Comment: The problem is [operator precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) which is fixed properly in this answer. The original `WHERE EXISTS (...)` would be just as efficient as an implicit or explicit join.